# Tag not working with an image in the same folder

Tags: html

I'm learning HTML and I have a question. (I'm on the basics, FYI)

I'm having troubles using this tag:

```html
<img src="images/web_Image_01.JPG" style="border:5px solid black; float:left; margin: 0px 25px 0px 10px;" />
```

For this image, I'm not sure what happened if it was in the same folder as the Girl in front of the computer image. So I had literally to copy and paste this path:

```html
<img src="../images/Excel-Let-Function-01.PNG" alt="image in subfolder"  style="border:5px solid blueviolet;float:left; margin: 5px 25px 0px 10px"/>
```

To get the image be visible. in the new practice page. The image of the girl in front of the computer worked fine in another HTML file, I used it this way:

```html
<img src="images/web_image_02.JPG">
```

So I tried to use this image `Excel-Let-Function-01.PNG` that is in the same folder as the girl in the computer, using the same tag and it didn't work. Can it be because one is `.JPG` and the other `.PNG`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: Your question gets asked here every day and always returns the same answer. Your path is likely wrong https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=img%20not%20showing

Answer (score 0):

It won't be because one is a JPG and one is a PNG.

I am a bit confused by your question so I'll cover a couple of possibilities and, better yet, give you some background.

First, the only reason I can think of that **src="../images/..."** worked and **src="images/..."** did not would be if you have your HTML page in a subfolder and the images in an "images" folder. The first reference says "go up one level, then down into the images subdirectory - which would work. The second say "look for the file in an images directory beneath the one I am in". Which won't work unless the HTML file is in the top level directory.

Typically, your main HTML files (e.g. index.html and other primary pages) are at the top level and, for larger sites, secondary pages are kept in dedicated subdirectories (e.g. /sales/salesfile.html). Images should be kept in a dedicated directory under the top level directory (e.g. "/images") or on a CDN (don't worry about that part until you advance).

To make sure your images will be found no matter where your HTML page is located, you can use src="/images/imagename.png".  This says "start at the top level and look for a directory called images, then return the file named imagename.png.

Hope this helps!

Comment: What if both images were in the same folder. That's what tricks me. Both images are in the same subfolder, so I don't understand why src="images/... would work for one image and not for the other. I couldn't upload images because I'm new in this page.
And thank you for taking your time answering my question.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. I would check that you have the names precisely correct, double-check on their location, and make sure there are no attributes that are actually hiding the image. For example, if you were to set opacity or size, etc. to zero, the image would not be shown. If you set the position to be somewhere off the page, you wouldn't see the image as well.

So, ultimately: stay with an absolute path (src="/images/...") to simplify your life, check your path names carefully, consider whether attributes are hiding the image and you'll find success.

Comment: If this helps you solve the problem, please remember to "accept" my answer!

Comment: And one last thing strikes me about your question. One image uses underscores (web_image_01) and the other is shown with dashes (Excel-Let-Function-01). Could you perhaps have that wrong? Is the actual image Excel_Let_Function_01?  After all, underscore and dash are distinct characters even if they are easy to confuse visually.

Comment: To avoid typo issues I always copy and paste the image name from the image itself.  I wanted to stick to src="/images/... to simplify my life but it didn't work.
(Where do I accept your answer, they are helping me a lot)